How to count 0 or >0 rows in the EXCEPT query?
I have a query like
SELECT  ct=COUNT(*)
        FROM ( select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t1 except select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t2 where ... )

But by fact the result ct used as ct>0.
How to change/optimize the query above?

Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get? It will help make the question clearer

The only way to filter by an aggregate result in SQL, the language, is to use HAVING, eg HAVING COUNT(*)>0 or wrap the entire query in a CTE or subquery. The effect is the same. It doesn't matter what's in the FROM clause. The count is only available after the results have been identified, grouped and selected

As for How to change/optimize, what do the actual tables contain and by what logic do you want to exclude rows? You could use WHERE t1.ID NOT IN (select t2.ID from T2) for example. The server would check the primary keys of the two tables to find the rows that only exist in T1

I don't understand what you mean with But by fact the result ct used as ct>0., can you explain what you're looking for and how the data looks

You can use like WHERE EXISTS ( select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t1 except select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t2 where ... ) or CASE WHEN EXISTS( select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t1 except select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t2 where ... ) THEN ...END

@ValNik that's still very expensive. Besides, we don't know if the count is needed or not

@PanagiotisKanavos,  in such a concise context of the question, the cost of the request does not matter:)

A full table scan on a 100K row table that compares all column values matters a lot. Especially when it can be replaced with a fast check on the primary keys. The question is unclear which is why it's already closed.

I think the OP is interested in comparing tables - for testing or migration or something similar. Looking at the above query, the column order is recorded as it is described in schema. There is no consideration of indexes. Since this is a one-time operation, there is no performance consideration either. Rather, it is about the convenience of checking a large number of tables. If we are really talking about query performance, the question can be considered not asked.

Original Query:
SELECT  ct=COUNT(*)
        FROM ( select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t1 except select f1, f2, ..., f52 from t2 where ... )

i edited to test with some dummy data:
SELECT  ct=COUNT(*)
        FROM ( select * from works w1 except select * from works w2 where w2.company_name = 'Company1' )

got this:
(1 row affected)
Table 'works'. Scan count 2, logical reads 15, physical reads 1, ...
edited version:
if exists (
    select *
    from works w1
    except
    select *
    from works w2
    where w2.company_name = 'Company1'
)
begin
    select 1 -- logic for when count(*) > 0
end

Table 'works'. Scan count 2, logical reads 11, physical reads 1, ...
You can also add else for when count(*) = 0
Basically, if exists will stop after the first occurrence of any match in the except clause, where count(*) will keep going until it gets the exact count number. This should improve performance imo.

This harms performance. Scan count 2 means the server had to scan all rows for both tables. The query depends on the order of columns too, easily resulting in incorrect results if the columns don't match exactly

I think the cost of scanning tables is noticeably less than the cost of sorting these tables into a significant number of columns. It is unlikely that there is at least one suitable index. In this case, the EXCEPT operation will undoubtedly require sorting.

If there's no index the table should be fixed. Besides, why do you assume that the server doesn't spool and sort the data to speed up the scans? You can't make such assumptions without looking at the execution plan.
